# How do I pass an ID to a drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql

When a user selects a method from a drop down menu, an event should be fired. I have a check box that gets a ID from the database and based on that ID you can add or remove a user from a drop down menu.

```
    var ajReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function (e) {
            switch ($(this).text()) {
                case "Add":
                      Do something...

                   break;

                case "Remove":
                    var id = $(this).attr("Remove-something");
                        SomeAjaxMethod(id)
                    break;
            }
        }); });
```

This is where I am creating my check boxes:

```
row += '<td><input type="checkbox" class="Remove" Remove-something= "' + msg[data].ID+ '"></td>'
```

So the question is, that if I tick one of the check boxes (which will contain ID for a record that will be used to delete that specific record). And if I then come down to drop down menu and select "Remove" option it should pass that ID to some Ajax method and remove that record from the database. I am getting 500 error. I think it's because I am calling SomeAjaxMethod(id) method inside document.ready function.

Comment: What's the relationship between the `<a>` tag being clicked and the checkbox?  You're using `this` to reference both of them, but I'm assuming they are not the same element.

Comment: the issue is in your server side code `500` is an internal server error

Comment: I would say, whatever!!

Answer (score 1):

Your "remove" case probably should look something like:

```
case "Remove":
  var id = $('.Remove:checked').attr("Remove-something");
  SomeAjaxMethod(id)
  break;
```

You're using `this`, but the context of `this` is the clicked dropdown item.  You need a different selector in order to grab the checked checkbox and get the `Remove-something` attribute.

Comment: I am getting an error of: Could not find stored procedure 'UPDATE Table SET ColumnName= ColumnName^ 1 WHERE ID=@ID'. What am i doing wrong here, i search few web pages but i dont understand?

Comment: That's on your server side.  What's your server-side language?  It looks like you're trying to execute a direct SQL statement as a stored procedure.  If you're using .NET, make sure you set your `SqlCommand`'s `CommandType` property to `StoredProcedure`.  The default value is `Text` (or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function (e) {
    var ele = $(this);
    switch (ele.text()) {
        case "Add":
            Do something...

            break;

            case "Remove":
            var id = ele.attr("Remove-something");
                SomeAjaxMethod(id)
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't work, when i add a brake point to var id = ele.attr("Remove-something"); on id it says undefined?. it should be getting a value which i selected from a checkbox